# Adobe Photoshop 2020 Menu Disappeared (NOT the toolbar)

Tags: graphics-card, adobe-photoshop, user-interface, integrated-graphics, app-menu

As can be seen on the screenshots below, the titles in the menu bar and each window disappeared. It seems that the menu itself is still there because I can choose options blindly clicking on the buttons where they supposed to be.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwKSX.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2acJ.png]

The issue happened after a sudden computer power cut during work in Photoshop. Pressing "F" to change the view mode or choosing another workspace or even reinstalling the program doesn't help.

Windows 10,

AMD Radeon R5 Graphics, AMD Radeon R8 M445DX

Comment: What if you hold down CTRL-ALT-SHIFT (or whatever the keys are) before starting Photoshop? That should put the program into safe mode, and allowing you to go back to system default settings.

Comment: @LPChip, I put Windows in the safe mode, and PS didn't run: nothing happened after [initialization](https://imgur.com/a/XxOph7T). In the usual mode PS opens, but still with the same interface issue

Comment: I did not mention putting Windows into Safemode. I mentioned running Photoshop into safe mode.

Comment: @LPChip, Could you please give some details? Can't find PS safe mode on the Internet, and Ctrl+Alt+Shift doesn't seem to be working

Comment: you double-click the icon and then immediately hold alt-ctrl-shift. It should ask you if you want to reset your preferences. Click yes, and it should be in this special safe mode.

Comment: @LPChip, Oh, now I see. I've done it, but nothing changed. I asked also on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/hv7dz3/adobe_photoshop_2020_menu_disappeared_not_the/), and it seems this is a problem of computers with several video drivers. I tried to turn off one video card and it helped, but I'm not satisfied with such a brute method. I also haunted by the fact that earlier all worked perfectly with two video cards switched on

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me a couple of times.

In my case, for some reason the toolbar is undocking itself and overlaying on top of the menu bar. If I click the window 'restore' button on the top right (next to close), or double left click the blank area on the menu bar, to resize the window, the menu reappears. I can then redock the toolbar in the correct place.

I hope this works in your case also.